# Angular 2 - Child routes load parent component

Tags: angular, routes, angular-cli

I am trying to get my routing to work in my Angular 2 application.

Here is the code I am using in the `app.routes.ts` file

```
export const ROUTES: Routes = [
  { path: '',      component: PublicComponent, data: { title: 'Heroes List' } },
  { path: 'home',  component: PublicComponent },
  { path: 'admin',  component: PrivateComponent, children: [
    { path: '', component: PrivateComponent },
    { path: 'account-settings', component: AccountSettingsComponent, children: [
      { path: '', component: UserInformationComponent},
      { path: 'user-information', component: UserInformationComponent},
      { path: 'companys-information', component: CompanysInformationComponent}
    ] },
  ] },
  { path: '**',    component: NoContentComponent },
];
```

Every time I try to navigate to one of the child routes it loads up the parent route.

So lets say for example I go to:-

`http://localhost:4200/#/admin`

It pulls in the correct component PrivateComponent.

But when I navigate to:-

```
http://localhost:4200/#/admin/account-settings
```

Or any children of the account settings it loads up the `PrivateComponent` and not the `AccountSettingsComponent` or `UserInformationComponent` as stated in the code you can see above.

Am I missing something in my code to get this to work?

The application was generated using Angular CLI.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Angular is a SPA(Single Page Application) platform, so it will have a technique for single paging. You need to include `<router-outlet>` into your `PrivateComponent` to let `Angular` loads child routes' components there. `Router-outlet` shows the place where child component will be loaded.

For more see [**Defining Child Routes**](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/routing/child_routes.html)

Answer (score 14):

You will not need another `<router-outlet>` in the component.

Instead of defining a `component` in the parent route have a root path in children that points to the parent, like so:

```
{ path: 'admin', children: [
    { path: '', component: PrivateComponent },
    { path: 'account-settings', children: [
        { path: '', component: AccountSettingsComponent},
        { path: 'user-information', component: UserInformationComponent},
        { path: 'companys-information', component: CompanysInformationComponent}
    ] },
] },
```

On the other hand I can see the benefit of using an additional `<router-outlet>` if you want to display a common element for each child routes i.e. a header.